# uninitialized constant Twilio::Rest Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, twilio

I keep getting an `uninitialized constant Twilio::Rest` error, cannot figure out what I have done wrong.  My code is below.

dial Model

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
class Dial < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :send_call

    private

    def send_call
        #begin
            account_sid        = 'sid'
            account_auth_token = 'auth'
            caller = '+14693514939'
            numbers = Number.find_by_sql('select phone from numbers')

            @client = ::Twilio::Rest::Client.new account_sid, account_auth_token

            numbers.each do |dial|

                @client.account.calls.create(
                        :from => caller,
                        :to => dial,
                        :url => 'http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=hello%20this%20is%20a%20test%20call%20please%20hang%20up&')
            end
        #rescue
            #false
        #end
    end
end
```

My dial view

```
<%= button_to "Call", action: "create" %>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be the first :: throwing it off. Try:

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, account_auth_token
```

instead of

```
@client = ::Twilio::Rest::Client.new account_sid, account_auth_token
```

Examples: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/master/examples/examples.rb

Also see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/master/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb  - looks like REST should be capitalized.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio. You've hit the nail on the head here, there is no `Twilio::Rest` module, it is capitalised as `Twilio::REST`. Thanks for jumping in and answering!

Comment: I wrote this first in a script, and then transferred over into rails.  Cant believe I missed the Twilio::REST.  Thanks guys